# Issue with GestureOverlayView/Multitouch on Nexus One

Tags: android, multi-touch, gestures, android-2.2-froyo, nexus-one

Problem: I have multitouch unintentionally generating a single stroke
gesture.

I'm using a GestureOverlayView over the entire screen and not attempting to use multitouch at all. I'm using `android:gestureStrokeType="single"`. One of my gestures is a horizontal left to right, like a swipe. It works just fine. The problem is that if I touch and hold the left side of my screen, then at the same time touch the right side and hold, then let go of the
left, then let go of the right, my `OnGesturePerformedListener` gets called and it indicates that the horizontal gesture has occurred. Could this be related to some of the multitouch problems on the Nexus One? Is there any way for me to detect this as a bogus gesture?

I'm seeing this problem on my Nexus One (2.2.1) but my code has to remain 1.6 compatible for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an AMOLED problem I believe. I have the HTC Desire and I've run into similar problems. For example, if you have the lock screen up, hold your right thumb on the Sound tab, and then place your left thumb opposite, and lift up your right, it will launch the tab at full speed to the other thumb.

I would recommend enabling multitouch, and then teach it to ignore the second finger.

But I believe you will have similar problems with earlier models, specifically the ones made before Android had multitouch in its platform (HTC Dream, Magic etc).

Comment: Since first posting this question, I've worked with Multitouch a bit and sure enough, the Nexus and a few other early devices have well publicized problems with Multitouch that cause this kind of behaviour.